# Choosing a set of devices with a faulty one

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A set of smart phones includes 20 devices, three of which are faulty.
>
> 1. In how many different ways we can pick 4 devices such that exactly one of them is faulty if we pick the devices **without replacement** ?
> 2. Suppose we randomly pick 4 devices. What is the probability that we picked exactly one faulty device when we pick devices **without
>      replacement** ?

**My solution:**

1. We can pick one faulty device in 3 ways **AND** we can pick a first non-faulty device in 17 ways **AND** we can pick a second non-faulty device in 16 ways **AND** we can pick a third non-faulty device in 15 ways, thus we can form a set of 4 devices with exactly 1 faulty device in it as follows (assuming the order **DOES** matter):
   $$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     3 \\ 
     1 
   \end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     {17} \\ 
     3 
   \end{array}} \right) \cdot 4! = 48960$$ Now, if the order **DOES NOT** matter we have $$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     3 \\ 
     1 
   \end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     {17} \\ 
     3 
   \end{array}} \right) = 2040$$
2. $$P({\text{exactly one faulty)}} = \frac{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     3 \\ 
     1 
   \end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     {17} \\ 
     3 
   \end{array}} \right)}}{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
     {20} \\ 
     4 
   \end{array}} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{4!}}{{4!}} = \frac{8}{{19}} \approx 0.42$$

The question is how do we know if in part 1. we need to consider the order or not? Also i have noticed that the probability in part 2. does not depend on the order, since we can simply cancel the permutation part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is really simple:

$$\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{20-3}{4-1}$$

For the second question, simply divide the previous result by:

$$\binom{20}{4}$$

Comment: In your first result we get $3 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 \cdot 15$, but what about the position of the faulty device in a set of four relative to the other devices? Shouldn't we also consider it?

Comment: @user_777: What position are you talking about? Your question says "such that exactly one of them is faulty". There's no position here.

Comment: Suppose we have two sets $\overline F  = \{ a,b\} $ and $F = \{ c,d\} $ and we have a set $A = \overline F  \cup F$. I denoted $\overline F $ - non-faulty set. Now, consider the case when we need to form a set of 3 devices with exactly 1 faulty device. We can do it in $\left( {\frac{2}{1}} \right)\left( {\frac{2}{1}} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{1}} \right)\left( {\frac{3}{1}} \right) = 12$ such as $cab,cba,acb,bca,abc,bac,dab,dba,adb,bda,abd,bad$

Comment: Tell me why in my example i multiply at the end by 3 and why in the original example i should not multiply by 4?

Comment: @user_777: Listen, you choose $1$ out of $3$ faulty devices, and the remaining from the remaining (i.e., $3$ out of $17$). That's it. Don't think about positioning, or permutations of the given devices. If you do that, then it is equivalent to choosing **WITH** replacement.

Comment: How is that choosing with replacement if based on a simpler case that i analyzed to generate the solution for a larger problem. In case we have 4 devices 2 of which are faulty and we want to pick 3 devices with exactly 1 faulty then we can have any of $cab,cba,acb,bca,abc,bac,dab,dba,adb,bda,abd,bad$. I don't get it what is considered a replacement. I'm simply relying on a simpler case. You may be right but i need a better explanation why we ignore the order we pick those devices.

Comment: @user_777: Imagine you reach your hand and pick all $4$ devices **at once**.